# AWS Educate - Cannot run EC2 instance from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I joined a class on AWS Educate. While I can create and run an EC2 instance from the AWS Console, I cannot do the same from the AWS CLI (v2). I set `~/.aws/credentials` as requested.

```sh
$ aws ssm get-parameters-by-path --path "/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest" --region us-east-1  # works ok

$ aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name mykey --output text > mykey.pem  # works ok

$ aws ec2 run-instances \
    --image-id resolve:ssm:/aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 \
    --instance-type t2.micro \
    --key-name mykey
```

The last command returns the following error.

```
An error occurred (SsmAccessDenied) when calling the RunInstances operation: 
User: arn:.../user=my.email@here is not authorized to perform: 
ssm:GetParameters on resource: arn:.../aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2
with an explicit deny
```

While I can stick to the AWS Console, I would like to make things as automatic as possible. Any hints?

Comment: Do you (your aws user) have permission policy with `ssm:GetParameters` and `ssm:GetParameter` action on all or on aws ssm resource? you can check your policy IAM for this. your command is failing because your aws user do not have permission to perform `aws ssm get-parameters --names /aws/service/ami-amazon-linux-latest/amzn2-ami-hvm-x86_64-gp2 --region us-east-1`, which is internally used in your last command. For more details, you can use `--debug` to aws cli command, which prints verbose logs.

Comment: Credentials on AWS Educate accounts are limited in what they can do. You could probably provide an actual AMI ID in `run-instances` and it would likely work.